# Is there a easy way to debug a Hadoop streaming code?

Tags: hadoop-streaming

I would like to know if there is a simple way to debug my Hadoop code. Currently, I have to run the whole task and wait more than a minute in order to read the error message in Java, on the terminal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`cat input_folder/* | <map task> | sort | <reduce task>`

Or even:

`cat input_folder/* | <map task> | sort`